Is a pure copper cathode necessary in the electrolytic refining of copper?
In the electrolytic refinement of copper, I'm unsure as to why the cathode should specifically be made of high-purity copper.

Would using an inert cathode (like graphite or platinum) work just as well, or are there other factors I'm missing?
What cathode would have been used during the first electrolytic refinement of copper, when high-purity copper was not yet available?

Many sources I've read (such as these 2 on chem.libretexts: Refining of Copper and The Extraction of Copper)
state, together, that nodes have to be impure copper and cathodes have to be high-purity copper.

In such a cell a thin sheet of high-purity Cu serves as the cathode, and the anode is the impure Cu which is to be refined.


The purification uses ... impure copper anodes, and strips of high purity copper for the cathodes

Most of them do a good job of explaining the impure copper anode. I know that the impure reactive copper anode is necessary because the oxidation of the anode into copper(II) ions maintains the concentration of copper(II) sulfate, and is where the refined copper comes from.
Cu(s)  → Cu²⁺(aq) + 2e⁻
Yet, they tend to skip over the high-purity cathode part. There seems to be no need chemically for a reactive cathode at all, let alone copper with high purity, since the reduction does not involve the cathode.
Cu²⁺(aq) + 2e⁻ → Cu(s)
It looks to me that any cathode less reactive than copper should work fine chemically. However, I see one practical benefit of using high-purity copper - there is no need to remove the deposited copper from the cathode. I'm also wondering if there would there be other chemical/practical benefits in doing so apart convenience in this regard.
Lastly, I am curious about the kind of cathode would have been used instead of high-purity copper when electrolytic refinement was first attempted, since no high purity copper would have been available, but I can't really find anything on that.
Any clarification on the role of the cathode material in the electrolytic refinement of copper would be greatly appreciated!

Since the purified copper is collected from the cathode, it makes sense to simplify the next process (separating the refined copper from the cathode material) by eliminating it entirely (starting with pure copper). How did this start? They used the best copper they could get as the result will be purer than the initial batch and this process can be repeated.

Those sites skip explaining the copper cathode as it is (should be) self-explanatory.
Using copper cathodes is not necessary in context of electrochemistry or physical chemistry. Any reasonable cathode material would do.
But in context of industrial scale technology, using other cathodes but the electrochemical grade pure copper does not have any practical sense. The electrode "seed" make the core of future pure copper block. Having in the end copper + something else would create the unnecessary problem of later separation of this material from copper. In the case of platinum there would be the huge price, as this process is scaled up for industrial use.
To address where they got the first pure piece of pure copper:

The electrochemical method is not the only method for copper purification.
Even if there was no other method, starting with impure copper blocks for both electrodes can still lead to obtaining pure copper, possibly in multiple steps.

If it was refining of other metal, the natural choice would be a cathode from that metal. Not necessary, but other options would not make practical sense.
Similarly for the anode. It is copper refining - using as an anode anything else but impure copper does not make sense.

I agree that there being no need to remove the deposited Cu from the cathode is an advantage of using a pure Cu cathode.
The other major issue here is the quality of the electroplating. Using pure Cu as a cathode has a "templating" effect meaning that the deposit will be smooth and grow as a uniform layer. In the ideal case, probably not achieved in the practical situation, the deposited atoms would just slot into their correct sites in the growing crystal. Other inert materials could be used, but adhesion of the film may not be as good as the lattice matching (correct atomic spacing) is poor.
For the anode we are dissolving it and so the structure and impurities don't matter. We can tolerate impurities since there will be more impurities in the bath itself.
As for the case of the first attempt when we don't have pure Cu for the cathode (assuming we have no other source), one can live with the poor situation, which will result in a purer result than the anode. Then the second time (in a clean bath) we can repeat the process to get a better result.

The cathode (a thin copper sheet) is simply left in the final product of the refinery (a thick copper plate) - no one needs them separated, they are the same substance.
The new cathode sheets are made by recycling a small amount of the refinery's own production (onsite) and they are exactly as much pure.
